# Gamemaker not able to connect on port when running Debugging Mode

Tags: debugging, connection, port, game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

I currently am unable to debug in GameMaker as it keeps saying "Unable to connect on port ####, please change value at General Settings->Debugging->Debugger Port" everytime I try launching the debug option.

I have tried changing ports and enabling real-time debugging. I also tried once disbaling the firewall thinking that was stopping the connection but to no avail. I am unsure as to why this is happening.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You may have windows firewall enabled, you need to disable it.